# Remove a specific image in a simple html dom scrape variable

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I've created a below foreach statement which goes through all images in $gosu_full->find('img'). However there is a specific image i want to remove which is where `$img->src == $gosu_img`. so far i've tried to set `$img->src` to a empty string and to `unset($img)` but nothing works. What can i do inorder to remove it?

```
foreach($gosu_full->find('img') as $img) {
                if  (stripos($img->src,'http://www.gosugamers.net') == true) {

                } else {
                    $img->src = "http://www.gosugamers.net" . $img->src;


                    if ($img->src == $gosu_img){
                        unset($img);

                    }
                }



}
```

Comment: please use a js alert to check if your condition parameter is correct. Please elaborate on the question if you need an answer

Comment: i just want it to delete the `$img` in the if statement

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue both `unset()` and `$img->src = '';` works fine for me. I think their is an issue with if condition itself. try giving an string in place of `$gosu_img` manually and test.

Comment: I've tried just to set a attribute using `$img->setAttribute('class', 'delete-image');` inside the if statement and works fine, so should not be anything with the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rewrite html code of img tag

```
$img->outertext = '';
```